# Search engine indexing - any alternatives to PhantomJs snapshots for SEO?

Tags: node.js, seo, search-engine, phantomjs

There are many javascript frameworks like Angular, Flight JS or Ember, that use the model-view-controller approach. This often screws up SEO, because the javascript model data can hardly be read by search engines. Using Node and PhantomJs and such you could make readable "screen shots", but I think this is a pretty ugly work-around.

**My question:** in web pages, is there any alternative to get the model to be indexed by search engines without maintaining a bunch of duplicate snapshots?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 3):

The [Render](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr) framework that AirBnb built on top of backbone.js allows server-side rendering so your application can serve full HTML to search engine spiders.